Bias adjustment in a transformation - adjustment before and after transforming
Suppose $X\sim(\mu, \sigma^2)$ (I'm happy to also assume normality), and let $Y = h(X)$ where $h$ is at least twice continuously differentiable. I want an approximation of $E(Y) = E[h(X)]$.
One approach that I'm confident about is based on a Taylor approximation
$$ Y = h(X) \approx h(\mu) + h'(\mu)(X-\mu) + \frac12h''(\mu)(X-\mu)^2 $$
so that taking expectations,
$$ E(Y) \approx h(\mu) + \frac12h''(\mu)\sigma^2 $$
(the middle term is zero).
This is exact in the case where $h(x)=x^2$, where we get $E(X^2) = \mu^2 + \sigma^2$.
So far, then, we have that we can obtain $h(\mu)$ and add a bias adjustment of $h''(\mu)\sigma^2/2$.
But another approach is to add a bias adjustment before transforming, so that
$$ E(Y) \approx h[\mu + \alpha(\mu,\sigma^2)] $$
I know some particular instances, the most obvious being the exponential case: $E[ \exp(X)] = \exp(\mu + \frac12\sigma^2)$, which is easily obtainable from the moment-generating function for the normal distribution, evaluated at 1. I have also seen an approach like this used in some of the documents (apparently no longer available) that used to accompany the R package MCMCglmm,  where $h$ is the inverse logit transformation and $\alpha$ was a moderately ugly function. But the point is, somebody smarter than me derived it, and now I want to know how.
In general, for a given $h$, how does one determine the function $\alpha()$ to use as an adjustment before transforming?
As you might guess,  the context of this question is actually bias correction when back-transforming predictions from a linear model with transformed response, or a generalized mixed model where there are random effects. Any insights will be appreciated.

Duan's 1983 Smearing Estimate:  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2288126.  (But this is after transforming and not before.)

@JimB Thanks! I looked at this reference and it seems problematic for me to use this in my particular situation, because it seems so dependent on the structure of particular linear models. My context is the emmeans package, which supports a very broad class of models. I do note that like Duan, my post-transformation correction does not rely on normality, it only relies on the mean and variance existing and that $h$ is twice differentiable.
